# Extract multiple files from tar to remote host

Tags: ssh, tar

I have a tar.gz file that has multiple dirs and files inside. I need to copy and extract a specific dir from it to a remote host.

I know how to do it with a single file, but have trouble with multiple files in a single command:

```
    tar zxOf /mnt/debug.tar.gz libr.so | ssh $MY_IP 'cat > /local/libr.so'
```

I currently workaround by extracting the whole dir locally, then use scp to copy:

```
tar -zxf /mnt/debug.tar.gz -C utils/foo --strip-components=1 tools/
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind the network overhead, you can do stuff like `cat debug.tar.gz | ssh remotehost tar xfz - -C /local foo bar baz` - ie stream the tar file to the remote host and do the `tar` extraction there.  It doesn't use disk space, but it does use network bandwidth.

Comment: I thought of this option, but the whole tar is quite large.

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple shell loop:

```
files="first second third"
for f in files; do
  tar xf thearchive.tar $f | ssh otherhost "cat > $f"
done
```